# Pass variable to python function from bash script

Tags: python, bash, function

I am really struggling trying to figure out to pass variables from a bash script to a python function I have made.  I have looked over numberous posts about the same issue and cant seem to understand what I am missing.

I have a python function script named fname_function.py:

```
from glob import glob
import os
import sys

first_arg=sys.argv[1]
second_arg=sys.argv[2]
third_arg=sys.argv[3]

def gFpath(reach,drive,date):
    list1 = glob(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(drive, reach, date,'*')))
    list2 =[]
    for afolder in list1:
      list2.append(glob(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(drive, reach, date, afolder, 'x_y_class?.asc'))))
    return list2

if __name__=='__main__':
    gFpath(first_arg,second_arg,third_arg)
```

And my bash script looks like:

```
reach="R4a"
drive= "D:\\"
dte="2015_04"

fnames=$(python fname_function.py "$reach" "$drive" "$dte")

for fname in $fnames; do echo "Script returned $fname"; done
```

The variables are being passed to the python script, but I cant seem to get `list2` back to my shell script.

Thanks,

Dubbbdan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just run the Python file directly, like `python fname_function.py "$reach" "$drive" "$dte"`

However, `sys.argv[0]` will be `fname_function.py` in this case, so you'll want to set `first_arg` to `sys.argv[1]` and increment the other numbers as well.

Also, you don't output anything in your Python script. You should make the end of your script read:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    fnames = gFpath(first_arg,second_arg,third_arg)
    for fname in fnames:
        print(fname)
```

which will print out 1 result from `gFpath` on each line.

Comment: `gFpath` was designed to return a list of file paths to the bash script.  How would I access `list2` from the  shell script?

Comment: You can assign the output to a variable in bash like so: `fnames=$(python fname_function.py "$reach" "$drive" "$dte")`. You can then loop over them with `for fname in $fnames; do echo "Script returned $fname"; done`. This might screw up if there are spaces in the filenames but I can't test on bash right now.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help!  How ever when i implement the `fname=...` suggestion I am getting `gfnames.sh: line 4: D:\: is a directory`  I was intentionally making it a directory i could change when I am working on different drives.  Any ideas on how to pass a variable that resembles a directory?