# How are wildcards passed to Python scripts on the command line?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, wildcard

I have a simple executable python script saved like /usr/local/bin/OscStr, which requires a file like an argument. I can call it with the terminal from anywhere.
But when I try `$OscStr *.log` it takes only one .log file.

Does wildcard work like a `for loop` or does it give multiple arguments to a command?

Comment: this is a bash question more than a python question. *.log will be expanded to every matching file in the current dir e.g. to `$ OscStr a.log b.log`

Comment: Yes, so the script takes multiple arguments and it should be ready for that. Thanks.

Comment: Does it only *get* one log file, or does it only try to *use* the first log file? What are the contents of `sys.argv`?

Comment: @AdamSrut, one place you can start is running `set -x` to tell the shell to log every command it runs -- that way you'll actually *see* the log filenames instead of the glob expression itself being passed to the python interpreter.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/31733193/5986907 for `sys.argv`

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/14155669/5986907

Comment: @chepner It takes only first .log file from sys.argv. So there will be the problem. 
Script now can take all the arguments from sys.argv so I solved the problem.